# Can I append something to object with prime?

Tags: javascript, append, push, addition

Can I append something like

```
'HI' : {fill : '#000'}
```

into 'stateSpecificStyles' below?

```
$('#map').usmap({
            'stateSpecificStyles': {
                'FL' : {fill: '#FFA500'}
            }
        });
```

The structure is like:

```
var defaults = {
...
// State specific styles. 'ST': {}
    'stateSpecificStyles': {},
...
}
```

The Github link for original file is https://github.com/NewSignature/us-map/blob/dev/jquery.usmap.js

Answer (score 0):

```
  const someSettings = {
     'HI' : {fill : '#000'} 
  };

  $('#map').usmap({
        'stateSpecificStyles': {
            'FL' : {fill: '#FFA500'},
            ...someSettings
        }
  });
```

You could just spread them in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! but is it possible to add new stuff by using a function? since it looks like this jQuery plugin cannot be overwritten once it's set, and I wish to add more stuff in a for loop.

Comment: @fornowfortest just mount it again with `$('#map').usmap({ ... })`

Comment: I figured it out. It should be like: 
    $('#map').usmap({
            'stateSpecificStyles': someSettings }});

Comment: @fornowfortest then you should add that as an answer  :)